# The Grade being given is wrong for any Grade not 16+ or 1, this is for cs50 readability in python

Tags: python, cs50

```
import cs50

text = cs50.get_string("Text: ")

letters = 0
words = 0
sentences = 0

for char in text:
    if char.isalpha():
        letters += 1

    if char.isspace():
        words += 1

    if char in [".", "!", "?"]:
         sentences += 1

L = (letters * 100.0) / words
S = (sentences * 100.0) / words
Grade = int(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8)

if (Grade < 1):
    print("Before Grade 1")

elif (Grade > 16):
    print("Grade 16+")

else:
    print(f"Grade {Grade}")
```

`your text`

The grade is correct if its 16+ or 1 but anything inbetween is wrong. The solution must be simple but i have no idea, it should be something to do with the L = (letters * 100.0) / words
S = (sentences * 100.0) / words
Grade = int(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8)
but i can't tell what it is. I'm fairly new to programming so i might just be doing it all wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

`Count the words.` How many words in that sentence? How many spaces? See the problem?

Additionallly, the `int` function drops everything after the decimal (it does not round).

Comment: I figured it out just had to change int to round and set words to 1, thanks.